# Using an array of hashes I need to compare two values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following array of hashes:

```
 [{"dwidNote"=>14, "StreetAddress"=>"250 Palm Valley Blvd.", "PropertyAddress"=>"250 Palm Valley Blvd."},
 {"dwidNote"=>16, "StreetAddress"=>"2801 Alaskan Way", "PropertyAddress"=>"2801 Alaskan Way"},
 {"dwidNote"=>17, "StreetAddress"=>"300 LAKESIDE DRIVE", "PropertyAddress"=>"300 LAKESIDE DRIVE  "},
 {"dwidNote"=>18, "StreetAddress"=>"3817 PARKDALE", "PropertyAddress"=>"3817 PARKDALE  "}]
```

I need to compare the values for the keys `StreetAddress` and `PropertyAddress` to see if they match. For the values that do not match I need to display the value for key `dwidNote`. How do I do this?

Comment: So could you tell us about the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your array is in a variable named `a` then this:

```
a.select{|e| e['StreetAddress'] != e['PropertyAddress']}.map{|e| e['dwidNote']}
```

will return this:

```
[17, 18]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Philip this has worked perfectly. As my skills progress I will make sure to contribute to the forum. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [{"dwidNote"=>14, "StreetAddress"=>"250 Palm Valley Blvd.", "PropertyAddress"=>"250 Palm Valley Blvd."},
 {"dwidNote"=>16, "StreetAddress"=>"2801 Alaskan Way", "PropertyAddress"=>"2801 Alaskan Way"},
 {"dwidNote"=>17, "StreetAddress"=>"300 LAKESIDE DRIVE", "PropertyAddress"=>"300 LAKESIDE DRIVE  "},
 {"dwidNote"=>18, "StreetAddress"=>"3817 PARKDALE", "PropertyAddress"=>"3817 PARKDALE  "}]

array.map { |x|
   x["dwidNote"] if x["StreetAddress"] != x["PropertyAddress"]
}.compact
```

would do the job

Comment: Now why would someone downvote rather than just point out the obvious oversight (`!=`).

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
arr = [{"dwidNote"=>14, "StreetAddress"=>"250 Palm Valley Blvd.", "PropertyAddress"=>"250 Palm Valley Blvd."}, {"dwidNote"=>16, "StreetAddress"=>"2801 Alaskan Way", "PropertyAddress"=>"2801 Alaskan Way"}, {"dwidNote"=>17, "StreetAddress"=>"300 LAKESIDE DRIVE", "PropertyAddress"=>"300 LAKESIDE DRIVE  "}, {"dwidNote"=>18, "StreetAddress"=>"3817 PARKDALE", "PropertyAddress"=>"3817 PARKDALE  "}]

arr.map { |h| h['dwidNote'] unless h['StreetAddress'] == h['PropertyAddress']  }.compact
#=> [17, 18]
```